# Geometric meaning of r-cycles, r-boundaries and homology groups for a geometric simplicial complex.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, intuition, simplex

I just started learning about algebraic topology, and some things are already not so clear to me. If I consider a geometric simplex $K$, I kind of understand what $H_0(K)$ is. it is a set of equivalent classes [x], where x is a vertex of the simplex, and [x]=[y] means that x and y are in the same connected components. Now for $H_1(K)$ (and more generally for $H_n(K)$, it is not so clear. Elements of $H_1$ are equivalent classes of edges of the simplicial complex, like [xy] or [uv]. [xy]=[uv] means that xy-uv is in the boundary of a 2-simplex. But is geometrically the boundary of a 2-simplex? Also what is a cycle **geometrically** of a 1,2,3,...-simplex?

Comment: do you know the formulas? Have you drawn some examples of complexes, plugged in the formula and seen what comes out? imo that's the quickest way to understand what the boundary operator and its kernel/image are really achieving.

Answer (score 1):

Geometrically, think of an n-simplex as an n-sphere ( it makes no difference whatsoever from a topological perspective ). So the n-th homology is simply put "how many ways there are to fit an n-shpere into my topological space". That means, just like the 0-th homology tells you how many parts there are in a space, the n-th lets you know how many n-dimension holes there are in the space you are examining. A cycle is nothing more than an element in the kernel of the boundary operator, homology takes those n-cycles and those n-boundaries and tries to figure out how many of them are redundant ( meaning how many elements in the kernel don't come from higher dimension boundaries ).
Now I know that my explanation can be a bit overly simplified, but to understand topology you are heavily reliant in your intuition rather than strict and vigorous mathematical calculations and logical steps due to the nature of the subject. Try to figure things out in a more instrictive rather than a more technical manner.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).